# ERROR: File 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2017, setup-project

**EDIT**: I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753412/setup-targeting-both-x86-and-x64) question, but neither methods given in the answer worked. I cannot create two different MSIs since I get the error that is the title of this question, and I tried Advanced Installer, only for my 32-bit virtual test machine to tell me the app can't run.

It was suggested to me that I should make my app compatible with both x86 and x64 architectures, but I cannot set the target as x86 in my Visual Studio Setup Project since I get this error upon Building:

```
ERROR: File 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
```

Here are the dependencies listed in the setup project:

[image: dependencies]

What do I need to do in order to make this compatible with x86? Can someone please help?

Comment: Completely different error than the "duplicate" question and I can't make separate MSI's. I already tried that.

Comment: The short answer is still that you need to create two MSI setups, one using all x86 code including referenced Dlls, dependencies, custom actions etc, and the other completely x64 code, dependencies and references. Basically it looks like your x86 setup is using x64 dependencies (from .NET) instead of the x86 ones.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That's what I'm trying to figure out, where to find the x86 version of that dll.